# Filter on 2 Conditions Including Date Not Working with Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm creating a console app to read emails for a certain user's email and process emails that meet a certain condition.  Here is sample code:

```
GraphServiceClient client = GetAuthenticatedClient();

string subject = "RE: ACTION NEEDED:";
string dt = "2018-10-5T00:00:00Z";
IUserMessagesCollectionPage msgs =
    client
    .Users["UserName@CompanyName.com"]
    .Messages.Request()
    //.Filter($"receivedDateTime gt {dt}")  // invalid filter
    .Filter($"startswith(subject, '{subject}') and receivedDateTime gt {dt}")
    .Select(m => new { m.Subject, m.ReceivedDateTime, m.From, m.Body })
    .Top(100)
    .GetAsync().Result;
int msgCnt = msgs.Count;

Console.WriteLine($"Message count: {msgCnt}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

2 Issues:

1. I want this filter to work:

   ```
   .Filter($"startswith(subject, '{subject}') and receivedDateTime gt {dt}")
   ```

The `startswith` works by itself but with the date filter it errors.

2. I tried the date filter by itself and it is not working.  I get an invalid filter.  I added single quotes around the date with no luck.

   ```
   .Filter($"receivedDateTime gt {dt}")  // Get invalid filter
   ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> The startswith string operator is often supported. The any lambda
>   operator is supported for some APIs. For some usage examples, see the
>   following table. For more details about $filter syntax, see the OData
>   protocol.
>
> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters

**Not all query parament are supported in all Graph API.**

**Based on Marc's post update my answer too**:
If you want to use the DateTime as query paramenter to filter the mail, you should use the one of the following api about **messages**  :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2018-10-01 and startswith(subject,'{subject}')
```

Or

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2018-10-1 and startswith(subject,'{subject}')
```

**If you want to add date(2018-10-01) with time(T04:16:35Z)， then you should use the follow format**:

```
2018-10-05T04:16:35Z(yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ)
```

**If you just use the date without time, you can use the follow format**:

```
2018-10-5(yyyy-mm-d) or 2018-10-05(yyyy-mm-dd)
```

Comment: Month is a capital M, so that should be (yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ)

Answer (score 0):

You're using a malformed date. The value `2018-10-5T00:00:00Z` is missing a `0`. More specifically, the day should be `05`, not `5`:

```
 string dt = "2018-10-05T00:00:00Z";
```